# When to use Comma in this situation?

Tags: punctuation

We use comma to set off a quote. Example:

> Yesterday, Al came to me and said, "What are you doing?"

But when I want to express a thought to someone or myself, how do we punctuate it?

> I thought to myself, "Can't he see what I am doing?"

OR

> I said to myself, "Can't he see what I am doing?"

is it correct? Or is there any other way to punctuate it?

Comment: _"I thought,"_, _"He thought,"_ will do. No need _"myself"_ . _"Said"_ is when you really talked.

Comment: @XPMai Thanks :) yeah, no need for "myself."

Comment: http://writersrelief.com/blog/2008/07/characters-thoughts-punctuating-and-formatting/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The punctuation is the same whether it's you thinking, or someone else saying. Basically, leading into any quoted phrase, you use a comma followed by the opening double-inverted-apostrophe